# What is the reciprocity fee for US citizens entering Argentina?

Tags: us-citizens, fees-and-charges, argentina

I am having the hardest time finding the exact reciprocity fee for US citizens entering Argentina.  Does anybody know what that amount is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reciprocity fee is currently US$160 for US citizens, and can now be paid online in advance via the website http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/accesibleingles/.  There is a PDF guide on paying the fee [available here](http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/pdf_varios/reciprocidad/Online_payment_instructions.pdf) (The entire guide is in English *except* for the country name of the US, which is in Spanish - "Estados Unidos")

Not surprisingly, this matches the fee the US charges for non-immigrant visa applications, which is currently [$160](http://travel.state.gov/visa/temp/types/types_1263.html#temp) - that's why it's called a "reciprocity fee".

Comment: Currently it **must** be paid online in advance.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2016, the reciprocity fee is **suspended** for US passport holders. That is, there is *no* reciprocity fee for US citizens entering Argentina at this time.

If you go to the official website, http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/accesibleingles/, you can see that the reciprocity fee is only for holders of UK and Canadian passports.

Answer (score 3):

The amount is currently US$160.  I recommend that you take care of it online *before* you leave, as it's not guaranteed that you'll be able to pay at immigration:

- At the land crossing between Santiago and Mendoza, you can pay the reciprocity fee at the border with cash or any major credit card.  But of course, this depends on their payment system being operational (source: [personal experience](http://www.fiveyearsabroad.com/2013/01/day-122-of-1827-mendoza.html)).
- If you fly into Aeroparque Jorge Newbery (AEP), you will **not** be able to pay the reciprocity fee upon arrival!  A friend of mine almost got denied entry because of this, but thanks to some (very expensive) international roaming, he was able to pay the fee online while he was waiting at the immigration booth (source: [friend's experience](http://www.fiveyearsabroad.com/2013/04/day-192-of-1827-buenos-aires.html))!

When you pay the fee, you will get a receipt that is valid for 10 years, so make sure you keep track of it!

Answer (score 3):

The US$160 rate was set by [Regulation 903/2014](http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/pdf_varios/tasas/dispo_903_2014.pdf). From [The Embassy of Argentina in United States of America](http://www.embassyofargentina.us/en/consular-section/reciprocity-fee-for-us-citizens.html):

[image: Reciprocity fee]